# How to get the retweets that a user make? Not the count. I want it in text form

Tags: twitter

I have seen many posts on stackoverflow asking for the retweets of a particular tweet that the user makes. But I am looking for the tweets that the user retweeted.

How do I go about doing this using code and without using Twitter's API? I have tried using snscrape but the retweets column is empty and from the research I have done, it seems impossible to get retweets that a user makes.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!